# Invalid mime type when consuming external api

Tags: spring, rest

I'm using Spring to consuming a rest api service. With Postman, it return code 200 (OK), but using Spring it return code 500:

> "Invalid mime type "text/html; charset=": 'value' must not be empty"

On Postman, I can see this:

[image: postman return]

Here is my code:

```
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8);
    headers.add("auth-token", this.getToken());
    headers.add(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
    headers.add(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT_CHARSET, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
    headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN));

    HttpEntity entity = new HttpEntity(headers);

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(0, new StringHttpMessageConverter(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));

    ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(this.getApiUrl(), HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);
    restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(0, new StringHttpMessageConverter(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));

    if (response.getStatusCode() != HttpStatus.OK) {
        throw new Exception(response.getStatusCode().toString());
    }

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    return mapper.readValue(response.getBody(), String.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

Response content type looks like "text/html", but this content type is missing in the accept headers

```
headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN));
```

try adding MediaType.TEXT_HTML

```
headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN, MediaType.TEXT_HTML));
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunetelly this not worked...same error